# Python unpack collections

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Python3

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = {'A6': 5, 'A3': 4, 'A2': 4, 'A1': 3, 'A5': 2, 'A10': 1 }
>>> res  = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     res[v].append(k)
... 
>>> res
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {5: ['A6'], 4: ['A3', 'A2'], 3: ['A1'], 2: ['A5'], 1: ['A10']})
>>> X = 3
>>> res = dict(list(res.items())[0:X])
>>> print(res)
{5: ['A6'], 4: ['A3', 'A2'], 3: ['A1']}
>>>
```

I would like to have the output printed in alphabetical order:

## Expected OutPut:

```
A1
A2
A3
A6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a dictionary by its keys using `sort()` and store that sorted result in an `OrderedDict()` to have a dictionary that is alphabetically sorted by its keys. Note that OrderedDict maintains insertion order, so if you insert another item after sorting the dictionary may no longer be sorted.

Here's an example from the `collections` documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes

```
# dictionary sorted by key
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the keys using `key` parameter in the default `sort` method:

```
d = {'A6': 5, 'A3': 4, 'A2': 4, 'A1': 3, 'A5': 2, 'A10': 1 }
res = []
for key in d.keys():
  res.append(key)
res.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1:])))

Out[1]: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A5', 'A6', 'A10']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with list comprehension. Then sort the resulting list, and finally print it out with `join`:

```
d = {'A6': 5, 'A3': 4, 'A2': 4, 'A1': 3, 'A5': 2, 'A10': 1 }

f = [k for k in d.keys()]
f.sort(key=lambda k: (int(k[1:]))) #sort list using the digit portion of the strings as the sorting key
print('\n'.join(f))
```

> Result

```
A1
A2
A3
A5
A6
A10
```